# Call dll file with and without visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, dllmain

Here is my code -

```
#include "main.h"
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;


extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    ofstream outfile;
    outfile.open("E:\\temp\\DllMain.txt");
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // attach to process
            // return FALSE to fail DLL load
        break;

        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // detach from process
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // attach to thread
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // detach from thread
            break;
    }
    return TRUE; // succesful
}
```

So the issues is, if Visual Studio is installed, this function is working fine, I am able to create DllMain.txt in e:\temp\ folder, but if Visual studio is not installed, problem with the function call. Explorer is unable to call this function. More information is given in edited section of what I am trying.

I am building a dll file with the following settings, check this link

[Property settings to make dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHkhX.png)

```
Editted Information ::
```

I am implementing "Send To" protocol of windows for mail client. So I need to build a dll and I have to register my application as a email client in windows. So if user selects my app for default email client like outlook and thunderbird, I needed a dll to do some task.

**Example - select a file -> (right click) send to -> mail recipient.**

Here explorer calls dll file. If visual studio is installed works perfect. Tried in a pc where Visual studio is not installed, Result error message and after that I tried after installing Visual studio and got a result I wanted.

I don't want to force my user to install MSVC runtime. Because If you are aware about thunderbird (Mozilla product), thunderbird is able to do this thing without MSVC runtime.

Comment: Problems (1) debug build; (2) probably dynamic runtime support (can't see linker settings in screen-shot) ; (3) putting code in `DllMain`.

Comment: "I am unable" is not an appropriate problem description.

Comment: @Hans You're right, the description is vague. But `DllMain` isn't called directly, instead it's an symptom a DLL is not loaded and the .txt file isn't written can suffice. So the the `VS is installed` is a good indication for the problem.

Comment: You could improve the question with the information, how you load the DLL. Are you using `LoadLibrary`, is there a load-time binding, or any 3rd party software that loads your DLL. What function actually fails.

Comment: @RichardCritten thanks, but I haven't written any code in that. It is just for the example so that I can know that my dll is called. I will check for the first and second problems, and I will write result here.

Comment: @HansPassant problem description is update. Thanks for telling, keep in mind from the next time

Comment: @harper Information is updated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To run a dll in windows without MSVC, One need to build a dll with Release Configuration.

You can change this from select Project -> properties -> Configuration manager -> Active Solution Configuration and change to Release (If it is not selected).

If MSVC is not installed and dll is of Debug configuration, then explorer is unable to read a dll, so dll must be of Release configuration only.

Answer (score 1):

You application or your DLL needs the MSCV run time installed. You get it as a redistributable depending on the VS version. E.g. for VS2008 your need this:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5582

If you want to distribute your DLL (or your application) then you should create an installer for your program that installs the run-time if required.

**Addition **:
If you want to avoid installing run-time DLLs, you can also change the C++ Compiler Settings. Select the Code Generation tab an select the appropriate non-DLL version of the run-time. This increases the size of your DLL but can help to avoid the dependency. 
Anyway I would recommend to create an installer.

Comment: Problem is updated. I have specified what I want to do. So no use of Installer for me and most of the pc in the world will have no MSVC, right? So I have to make dll which explore can call without MSVC.

Comment: @Bonny Moradiya Didn't you read my addition? With the compiler settings you shouldn't need the run-time DLL.